# WooCommerce checkout button position

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my WooCommerce form i have to buttons which are now like this:

[image]

I want them to be aligned all the way to the right so i went in the CSS and added `float:right`

Like this:

[image]

Only the first button goes all the way to the right like i want it. The other one stays inside the first column. Is there a way to change this? which file do i need to edit for this.

Thanks in advance

-Kevin

Answer (score -1):

Your question has not enough information , make sure both the buttons have different id's and css for both id's is required

Comment: one more thing the top button is a full width row while the bottom button is not full width it may b 50% of the page , your property is working , if you want the top button to b align same as the bottom button just give a unique id to the top button and apply the following css property 
#youridname
{
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}